# "unless" vs. "without": "the company would go bankrupt ___ cutting costs drastically"

Tags: word-choice

the sentence is

> During his meeting at the corporate headquarters, Mr. Breeding stated that the company would go bankrupt _____ cutting costs drastically.

(A) unless
(B) without

An answer is (B) because "without" is used for preposition

But i think that (A) also might be an answer

if "unless" is an answer, I think that unless "cutting costs drastically" is

used for conjuction and participial construction abbreviation

Answer (score 2):

In this particular construction, **unless** ***cutting*** is ungrammatical.

*Unless* could be correct—but only if the words that followed it were changed.

For instance:

> The company would go bankrupt unless **it** ***cut*** costs drastically.
>   The company would go bankrupt unless **costs** ***were*** **drastically** ***cut***.

---

Also note that if those words *were* changed, then *unless* would become the only acceptable answer, since *without* would not work with the new phrasing.

Given that the words are what they are, *without* is the only acceptable answer.

Answer (score -1):

*Unless **it cuts** costs drastically* would make it right, or we have to use *without*.